# Parse TSV file line to String array with split method

Tags: java, string, parsing

A database table has been exported as a .tsv file format. Now I have to generate a table from some specific columns of the exported tsv file using Java. In normal cases, I can separate each column by line.split("\t") method. The parsing logic is a little bit complicated. A field data may have a tab(\t). In that case, the field starts with ""some text and inner double quotations (") then the field tab(\t) and then there are other double quotations (") to start the new text. And the text ends with "". For example,
`""Java is a"    "Program Language""`. I my case I have to consider this as a single field value. 
**Whatever, I'm ading a demo data and my expeted result here**

So, currently getting this type of string from the tsv file line.

```
String str = "\"2023-01-03" +
                "\tpage_view" +
                "\t" +
                "\"\"Java is a\"\t\"Program Language\"\"" +
                "\t\"\"Windows 10\"\"" +
                "\t" +
                "\t" +
                "\t" +
                "\tandroid" +
                "\t" +
                "\"\"My User\"\"" +
                "\t" +
                "\t" +
                "\t";
```

**And my expected should be like bellow list**

```
[2023-01-03,
page_view,
,
Java is a  Program Language,
,
,
,
Windows 10,
android,
My User
]
```

I facing difficulty to write the regex. Kindly help me to write the regex.

Comment: *Now I have to generate a table from some specific columns of the exported tsv file using Java.* It might be a lot simpler to let the rdbms create the table and then just drop the columns you don't want

Comment: Nested delimiters in fields is tricky. If you're determined to parse the csv then use a proper API like OpenCsv

Comment: `String[] array = str.trim().replaceAll("[\"]", "").split("\t");`

Comment: Please correct your string and your expected output to make your question totally clear.

Comment: Also, don't try to use the split method with a pattern that describes the delimiter, but use the `matches` method with a pattern that describes the values.

Comment: Further to @CasimiretHippolyte's  suggestion it appears you can simply match `[^\"\t]+`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NVWZ2M/1) (Hello, Cas.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Hi Cary. If you do that, you can't obtain values enclosed between quotes or that contain tabulations: I wrote that: https://regex101.com/r/ftMHxT/1 , but solving the problem using the dbms (if possible) as g00se suggest it, is probably more simple.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, thanks, I misread the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, you can use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` to capture all the values which are immediately followed by a tab character, or the end of the sequence.

The regular expression pattern is as follows.

```
([^\t]*?)(?:\t|$)
```

Here is a method which will return a `List` of `String` values.

```java
List<String> split(String string) {
    List<String> split = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\t]*?)(?:\\t|$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String group;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        group = matcher.group(1);
        if (group.startsWith("\"\"")) {
            builder.append(group);
            if (group.endsWith("\"\"")) {
                split.add(builder.toString());
                builder = new StringBuilder();
            }
        } else if (group.startsWith("\"") && !group.endsWith("\"\"")) {
            if (!builder.isEmpty()) builder.append('\t').append(group);
            else split.add(group);
        } else if (group.endsWith("\"\"")) {
            builder.append('\t').append(group);
            split.add(builder.toString());
            builder = new StringBuilder();
        } else
            split.add(group);
    }
    return split;
}
```

If I provide the `String` value you provided, I get the following output.
Which, while is technically not what you provided as the expected output, it appears to be a valid result.

```
[
"2023-01-03, 
page_view, 
""Java is a"    "Program Language"", 
""Windows 10"", 
, 
, 
, 
android, 
""My User"", 
, 
, 
]
```